# In Files is it possible to sort folders together w files, rather than folders separate from files, like how files are sorted in the open/save boxes?

Tags: pantheon-files

In the elementary os open/save dialog box, folders are sorted alphabetically in with files.

E.g. if I had the following in a folder, they would be sorted in this order when I view them in the open/save dialog:

- a_file.txt
- a_folder/
- another_file.txt

Note that they're alphabetical, with the folder(s) mixed in with the files. This is actually my preferred way of sorting.

In Files, if I open the same folder with the same files and sub-folder inside it, it's sorted like this:

- a_folder/
- a_file.txt
- another_file.txt

Note that the folders are sorted first, and then the files come afterward.

Does anyone know if there is there any way to make Files in elementary os sort files and folders together, like the open/save dialog box does?

Comment: It is like that in my Files O.o...

Comment: Do you mean that folders and files are sorted separately, or together?

Comment: Sepearetely, e.g. : Ab.folder, Bb.folder, A.gif, B.gif etc.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no such option.

In fact, I'd find it very counterintuitive, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: Well, that's how it works on Mac OS, which I used for years before switching, and I much prefer it that way. ;) (You can put dates in yy-mm-dd format at the beginning of a set of folders and files and then everything is in order of date!)

Also: that's how the open/save dialog on elementary os works (try it in Scratch), so it's weird that it's inconsistent.

Comment: The inconsistency is weird, I agree. I always have a little confusion when I open the file selector dialogs.

Comment: Perhaps Files should honour the setting org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.sort-directories-first so that there is no inconsistency between the filechooser and the file browser.