# Sorting files in different maps (folders)

Tags: pantheon-files, libreoffice, file-management

I'll been using Elementary on regular basis for a couple of years now and I really like it.

But - when I open a map (folder) with Files the files are sorted fine - by maps and then filename, but when I open a map within Evolution and some other programs (gedit) files are sorted only by name (first a map beginning with A and then a file beginning with A) - that's bad. I just want the maps be sorted by type and name even form the program I use. Is it possible to make adjustment to achieve that?

Best regards
Bengt G Jacobsson
Uppsala, Sweden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Files is it possible to sort folders together w files, rather than folders separate from files, like how files are sorted in the open/save boxes?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2253/in-files-is-it-possible-to-sort-folders-together-w-files-rather-than-folders-se)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the behaviour of program such as gedit that use the Gtk+3 filechooser by changing the dconf setting org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.sort-directories-first  using dconf-editor or from the commandline. (gsettings set org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser sort-directories-first true).